# Is it a topological space

Tags: general-topology

Does $\mathbb{R},\emptyset,[-n,n]$ where $n$ is a positive integer forms a topology ? If not how can I prove it ?
 I was trying in the following method

$\cap_{n=1}^{n=k} [-n,n]=[-k,k]$ belong to $\tau$

But  This method does not work for infinite union of $[-n,n]$.So it is not a topology...

I felt some gaps in this argument.Or I am not satisfied with this argument.

Comment: Just because you can’t use the same argument twice doesn’t mean that the statement is wrong.

Comment: $$\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} [-n,n]=\mathbb{R}$$

Comment: I beg your pardon, but if $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbf N}$ is an infinite sequence tending to $+\infty$, $\;\displaystyle\bigcup_{k}[-n_k,n_k]=\mathbf R$, and if the infinite sequence is bounded, there is actually a finite number of intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collection is definitely a topology on $\mathbb{R}$. It is closed under finite intersection. It is also closed under arbitrary union since $\cup_{n\in F}[-n,n]$ is $[-m,m]$ ($F$ finite and $m=\max F \in \mathbb{N}$) or $\mathbb{R}$ (when $F$ is infinite).